# existence of locally translation-invariant Borel measure on Frechet manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

It is well known that the only locally finite, translation-invariant Borel measure on an
infinite-dimensional, separable Frechet space is the trivial measure.  I am wondering about an analogous proposition for Frechet manifolds (e.g., the manifold of Lorentz metrics over a candidate spacetime manifold, a $4$-dimensional, Hausdorff, smooth manifold).  Define the notion of "locally translation-invariant measure" as follows:  fix a point $p$ of the Frechet manifold, a chart $(O, \phi)$ containing the point and a measurable neighborhood $N$ of $p$ contained in $O$; then any translation of $N$ using the local Frechet linear structure that leaves $N$ entirely in $O$ preserves the measure of $N$.

Then I think the following is likely true:  There is no locally finite, locally translation-invariant Borel measure on an infinite-dimensional, separable Frechet manifold.  The proof would use probably use the fact that every infinite-dimensional, separable Frechet manifold is isomorphic to an open subset of the infinite-dimensional, separable Hilbert space (on which there is, of course, no such measure).  Is this result, or something close to it, or a counter-example, known?

Thanks!

Erik Curiel

Comment: Isn't this notion of local invariance chart-depending?

Comment: I'm assuming it holds for *all* charts and *all* subneighborhoods of the charts, so I don't think that's an issue.